# Is it mandatory to check "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" in HTTP Request Defaults for performance testing?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

During performance testing "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" should be checked or unchecked?

My analysis: "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" should not be checked. And cache also should not be cleared automatically.

Note: 
a. "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" option is not checked in Jmeter default recording template.

Which is the correct response time, if 500 user are iterating 2 scenarios 50 times.

My analysis: Need to refer "Transaction Controller - Sample Time [sum value]" in "View Results in Table" listener. Note, need to user parallel controller in order to handle parallel requests and need to refer max response time in that.

[image: Aggregate Report]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you're testing a web application you need to configure JMeter to behave like a real browser. Real browsers download these "embedded resources" like images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. and doing this in parallel (one main request followed by 6 threads to download the embedded resources). So you should:

   - Configure JMeter to download embedded resources
   - Do it using parallel downloads with i.e. 6 threads
   - Limit the resources location to the domain(s) you're testing to exclude 3rd-party resources like CDNs for scripts, banners from external sites, etc)
   - Cache: if you want to simulate "new" user each iteration you should clear the cache, if you want to simulate "returning" user - he should already have the resources in his cache and shouldn't download them.

     More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/)
2. We don't know what you're measuring, the response time for a single request or for the whole business transaction. Personally I would go for the single request (but including all the embedded resources and eventually [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests simulated by the parallel controller if any) and look not into the average response time but rather at 90% [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) as average can mask the problem while 90% percentile is the response time which 90% of the users will get.

Comment: Kindly confirm, For response time in Aggregate Report I have to refer, the 90% column "Total" row value correct? Kindly refer the newly added Aggregate Report image in question.

Comment: If you want to check responses instead of rendering UI, you can opt for this. Unchecking of "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" is worked for me.