# Is it necessary to use Http Cookie Manager in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

If the Http Request I am testing does not use any cookies, will using a cookie manager give better results? In Jmeter documentation using cookie manager is considered a good practice, but in this particular case it's my understanding that it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: If you are sure the http request need not any cookies,  then the cookie manager can be ignored. 
In fact, you still can use it and set the option: clear cookes each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well-behaved JMeter test must represent a [real user using the real browser accessing the system under test with 100% accuracy](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), it includes:

- Sending proper [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (including [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies))
- Downloading [embedded resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240112/is-it-mandatory-to-check-retrieve-all-embedded-resources-in-http-request-defau) and [caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) them
- Simulating user think times using [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
- Simulating [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests
- etc.

If the application you're testing doesn't use cookies, i.e. neither sends `Set-Cookie` header itself nor parses `Cookie` headers from the incoming requests then using HTTP Cookie Manager doesn't make any sense, it will only give you some overhead.